# Transcendence degree over arbitrary point given information over generic point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This question came up while attempting to do an exercise (12.5.C) in Vakil's FOAG (Dec 31, 2022 draft)—specifically, an exercise related to the proof of the following statement (questions about a special case of this theorem for irreducible $k$-varieties, which appeared in an earlier draft of FOAG, have been answered already, but as far as I am aware, no questions about this more general variant of the result has been asked on this website):

> Suppose $\pi: X \to Y$ is a finitely presented dominant morphism of irreducible [I'm guessing this is supposed to be "integral," since Vakil only discusses dominant morphisms for reduced schemes] schemes such that $K(X)/K(Y)$ (a finitely-generated field extension) has transcendence degree $r$. Then there exists a nonempty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that for all $q \in U$, the fiber over $q$ has pure dimension $r$, or is empty.

The very next exercise asks us to reduce this to showing that there exists some distinguished open subset $U$ of $Y$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U) \to U$ factors through $\mathbb{A}_U^r$ via a finite surjective morphism. Part of this reduction involves showing that each component of the fiber over a point of $U$ has dimension at least $r$. I've reduced this to showing that for $q \in U$ and $p \in \pi^{-1}(U)$ mapping to $q$, that $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{\kappa(q)} \kappa(p) \geq r$. Specifically:

> Let $B \to A$ be an inclusion of integral domains, and suppose $K(A)/K(B)$ has transcendence degree $r$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$ contracting to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$, is it true that $K(A/\mathfrak{p})/K(B/\mathfrak{q}) = \kappa(\mathfrak{p})/\kappa(\mathfrak{q})$ has transcendence degree $\geq r$?

How would I go about showing this? Is this result true? If $A, B$ are finite-type $k$-schemes for some field $k$, then this can be shown using the fact that $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{q})}\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) = \operatorname{tr.deg}_k{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})} - \operatorname{tr.deg}_k{\kappa(\mathfrak{q})}$ and an inequality about codimensions of fibers discussed before.

**Edit:** I just realized that, as stated, the reduction I proposed isn't true in general—however, I only need it to be true in the case that $p$ is a generic point of some irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(q)$, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal among primes of $A$ contracting to $\mathfrak{q}$. The following example shows how this fails in the general case: take $B = \mathbb{R}[x]$, $A = \mathbb{R}[x, y]$. Then $\mathfrak{p} = (x^2 + 1, y)$ is maximal in $A$ (quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$) and contracts to $\mathfrak{q} = (x^2 + 1)$ in $B$. The map of fraction fields induced by $\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x, y]$ is $\mathbb{R}(x) \to \mathbb{R}(x, y)$, which has transcendence degree $1$, but the induced map of residue fields $B/\mathfrak{q} \to A/\mathfrak{p}$ is the map $R[x]/(x^2 + 1) \to R[x, y]/(x^2 + 1, y)$, which is equivalent to the identity $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, which has transcendence degree $0$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is required to be minimal among primes contracting to $\mathfrak{q}$, then this problem doesn't exist in this case, since then $\mathfrak{p} = (x^2 + 1)$ in $A$ and the induced map is $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}(y)$.

Comment: Did you intend to drop the finite presentation hypothesis from the second statement? Asking it without that hypothesis is quite general, whereas your reduction should preserve that hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Yes, I meant for $A$ to be a finitely-presented $B$-algebra. Thank you for pointing that out.